# Unable to add ssh key in azure vm

Tags: azure, ssh-keys, ubuntu-server

I am the admin of this particular azure subscription. I had to add my ssh key to a ubuntu server. But when I try to add the ssh key through "Reset Password", After sometime I'll get the following error message.

VM agent on VM 'Server' has not reported latest status for extension 'enablevmaccess'. Please verify the VM has a running VM agent and can establish outbound connections to Azure storage.

What might be the issue? How to resolve this?

[Failed to reset ssh key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q8F9.png)

[vmaccess is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CAj6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two simple thing you might try;

1. Uninstall the VMAccess extension and try reset again.
2. Use the 'Run Command' to set/reset password.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

your first error tells you exactly why this happens. vm extension needs to talk to azure storage to report extension status. if it cant - portal operations might fail (this doesnt mean the extension failed; its just unable to report actual extension status).